# What is functional difference between UNION and OR?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder if `UNION` and `OR` in `WHERE` statement have any difference?

Using `UNION` statement with two different tables:

```
SELECT A.col
FROM A, B1
WHERE A.col = B1.col
UNION
SELECT A.col
FROM A, B2
WHERE A.col = B2.col
```

Using or in `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT A.col
FROM A, B1, B2
WHERE A.col=B1.col or A.col=B2.col
```

Except the performance difference, is there any difference on their meanings?

Comment: Did you even tried running it? First `UNION` will remove duplicates, second with `WHERE OR` you most likely get cross join. Please avoid using comma join syntax and use proper `JOIN/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN`

Comment: OR can't use indexes.  Union will remove duplicates if they exist.

Comment: @xQbert OR can use indexes. [OR expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda So it treats it as a union so it can use indexes but only in 12c+ and we don't know the version involved in the question.  Or can use indexes in 12c+ by having the compiler rewrite the query to unions at a cost; so I'd be better writing the unions to start with then.  Neat feature though.

Comment: Question: what is the functional difference between crane and steam roller? `Union` is to compose data from 2 **different** result sets. `Where` is to trim specific result set and `OR` is to compose such filter. Depends on your data, these queries may or may not return same result. Now, if your results were the same **independently** of what data you have in those tables, then come back and ask again

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tested it. In the example above, in (or in WHERE statement), the result returns more rows then I expected, such as A.col=B1.col=B2.col. Maybe WHERE statement retrieves all of that 3 tables(A,B1,B2) joined, is it right?

Comment: Please post some sample input data then post the outputs of the different queries run over that data.

Answer (score 0):

These queries are nothing alike.  First, you should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

If you ran them -- even on test tables -- you would quickly find the differences.

For instance, the `union` query removes duplicates.  The `or` query does not.

The `or` query does a Cartesian product of the tables.  So, if any of the tables is empty (such as `B1` or `B2`) then no rows are returned.  The `union` will return values from the other two tables.